# Take object name from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have some object with name and variables.

```
var data = [ {   "id": 144,
    "name": "Zagreb",
    "region": "",
    "iso": "HR",
    "country": "Croatia"},
{   "id": 145,
    "name": "Wellington",
    "region": "",
    "iso": "NZ",
    "country": "New Zealand"}];
```

For render dropdown I need only "name" and "country".

But, object can have other names with variables. Which I know.
So I have idea, write names that needs to render in array like.

```
var renderNames = ['name', 'country'];
```

At this moment i've stopped. I don't know how to get value from object using names from array.
As I see, it's must be something like that:

```
data.name == data. (do something) renderNames[1];
```

Comment: how do you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For render dropdown I need only "name" and "country".

If you want an array of names from this array

```
var names = data.map(function(value){return value.name});
```

similarly, for array of country

```
var countries = data.map(function(value){return value.country});
```

Comment: My guess is OP wants `keys` to be accessed from `array`

Comment: @RayonDabre maybe, but since he mentioned only that `I need only "name" and "country"` I am assuming that he somehow wants to use these two values for his dropdown rendering.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array with objects including name and country, this can work:

```
var dropdowns = data.map(function(obj) {
    return {
    country: obj.country,
    name: obj.name
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0ggxc3m/

Answer (score 0):

How about using Lodash? https://lodash.com

Then it's easy

```
_.map(data, function(obj) {
  return _.pick(obj, ['name', 'country']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) new in ES6

```
var data = [ {   "id": 144,
    "name": "Zagreb",
    "region": "",
    "iso": "HR",
    "country": "Croatia"},
{   "id": 145,
    "name": "Wellington",
    "region": "",
    "iso": "NZ",
    "country": "New Zealand"}];
data.map(element => element.name) // return an array of names
//[ "Zagreb", "Wellington" ]
data.map(element => element.country) // return an array of country
//[ "Croatia", "New Zealand" ]    
data.map(element => [element.name, element.country]) // return 2d array of name, country
// [ [ "Zagreb", "Croatia" ], [ "Wellington", "New Zealand" ] ]
```

or return an array of objects where properties are "name" and "country"

```
data.map( element => { return { "name": element.name, "country": element.country }; })
```

which yields:

```
[
        {
                "name" : "Zagreb",
                "country" : "Croatia"
        },
        {
                "name" : "Wellington",
                "country" : "New Zealand"
        }
]
```

Comment: And with destructuring, `data.map(element => element.name)` can be written as `data.map(({ name }) => name)`